# Use method return value inside linq where clause

Tags: c#, sql, linq, methods, lambda

here I have a linq query, which is working fine but I m trying to make it more readable. Basically, I am adding new DateTime range into the DB, but it can not intersect with the existing ones. I tried to write a method, pass the start and end times and use the return value inside where clause, but as I aunderstand, one can not use function inside query. Any suggestions on that?

```
var salariesInPeriod = await db.Salaries
                .Where(x => x.Id != salaryIdToIgnore)
                .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                .Where(x =>
                    //These filters check if there are any overlapping ends
                (x.StartDate <= startDate &&
                 startDate <= (x.EndDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue))
                ||
                (x.StartDate <= (endDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue) &&
                 (endDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue) <= (x.EndDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue))
                ||
                (startDate <= x.StartDate &&
                 x.StartDate <= (endDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue))
                ||
                (startDate <= (x.EndDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue) &&
                 (x.EndDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue) <= (endDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue))
                )

                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.StartDate,
                    x.EndDate
                })
                .ToListAsync();
```

And that's what I've tried:

```
public bool CheckIntersections(DateTime currentStart, DateTime newStart, DateTime? currentEnd, DateTime? newEnd)
    {
        if ((currentStart <= newStart &&
             newStart <= (currentEnd ?? DateTime.MaxValue))
            ||
            (currentStart <= (newEnd ?? DateTime.MaxValue) &&
             (newEnd ?? DateTime.MaxValue) <= (currentEnd ?? DateTime.MaxValue))
            ||
            (newStart <= currentStart &&
             currentStart <= (newEnd ?? DateTime.MaxValue))
            ||
            (newStart <= (currentEnd ?? DateTime.MaxValue) &&
             (currentEnd ?? DateTime.MaxValue) <= (newEnd ?? DateTime.MaxValue)))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

And then I tried to use the result inside query:

```
var salariesInPeriod = await db.Salaries
            .Where(x => x.Id != salaryIdToIgnore)
            .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
            .Where(x => CheckIntersections(x.StartDate, startDate, x.EndDate,endDate) == true)

            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.StartDate,
                x.EndDate
            })
            .ToListAsync();
```

Any ideas how to simplify that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use any function in your linq query. For better readability you can use extension methods:

```
public static class SalaryQueryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<Salary> WithIntersections(
        this IQueryable<Salary> salaries, DateTime currentStart, DateTime newStart, DateTime? currentEnd, DateTime? newEnd)
    {
        // return your query. Example:
        // salaries.Where(x=> x.DateTime > currentStart);
    }

    public static IQueryable<Salary> WithIgnoreId(this IQueryable<Salary> salaries, Guid id)
    {
        // return your query.
    }

    public static IQueryable<Salary> WithUserID(this IQueryable<Salary> salaries, Guid userId)
    {
        // return your query.
    }
}
```

And then use extension methods like this:

```
var salariesInPeriod = await db.Salaries
            .WithIgnoreId(salaryIdToIgnore)
            .WithUserId(userId)
            .WithIntersections(startDate,endDate)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: well, that query looks a lot better that way, but it means I need new class and inject a db factory.

Comment: You can use private methods instead of extension method in your current class but you should divide your queryable into two parts. var salaries = db.Salaries.Where(x=> x.UserId == userId);  salaries = CheckIntersections(salaries);  and in your CheckIntersections() method return your queryable.

Comment: Yeah, that would work I gues, just means that I would be querything every record, which is not the best way in regards of the performance, but I'm trying the salary extensions atm.

Comment: No. Until you your are working with IQueryable, your query doesn't execute on the database.  In this sample you should call ToListAsync() after calling CheckIntersections() method.

Comment: Hi Arsalan, I actually like you first solution and haven't used the extension methos before, so I learned something new and I didn't need to inject db context.

Comment: and sorry, I didn't see you comment about query exectuions, thanks